# Scipy.linalg.eig() giving different eigenvectors from GNU Octave's eig()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, octave, linear-algebra

I want to compute the eigenvalues for a generalized eigenvalue problem with lambda * M * v = K * v, where lambda is the eigenvalue, v is an eigenvector, and M and K are matrices. Let's say we have

```
K =

   1.8000 + 0.0000i  -1.0970 + 0.9550i
  -1.0970 - 0.9550i   1.8000 + 0.0000i

M = 

   209     0
     0   209
```

In Octave, if I do `[V,D]=eig(K,M)`, I get:

```
V =

   0.53332 - 0.46429i  -0.53332 + 0.46429i
   0.70711 + 0.00000i   0.70711 + 0.00000i

D =

Diagonal Matrix

   0.34555         0
         0   3.25445
```

However, if I do scipy.linalg.eig(K, b=M) using Scipy in python, I get a different result:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> import scipy.linalg
>>> K = np.mat([[1.8, -1.097+0.995j], [-1.097-0.955j, 1.8]])
>>> M = np.mat([[209., 0.], [0., 209.]])
>>> M
matrix([[ 209.,    0.],
        [   0.,  209.]])
>>> K
matrix([[ 1.800+0.j   , -1.097+0.955j],
        [-1.097-0.955j,  1.800+0.j   ]])
>>> D, V = sp.linalg.eig(K, b=M)
>>> D
array([ 0.00165333 -1.99202696e-19j,  0.01557155 +0.00000000e+00j])
>>> V
array([[ 0.70710678 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.53332494 +4.64289256e-01j],
       [ 0.53332494 +4.64289256e-01j,  0.70710678 -8.38231384e-18j]])
```

The eigenvalues should be the ones in the D array.

Why are the eigenvalues different in these two examples? Am I misunderstanding something?

edit: corrected typo and redid calculation.

edit: I used Octave 3.8.2. in Mac OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: eigenvalues/eigenvectors are not unique.

Comment: looks like Octave's eigenvalues are the same as scipy's, just scaled by 209.

Comment: FYI, eigenvectors aren't unique, but eigenvalues should be.

Comment: Unless there's degeneracy, the eigenvectors are unique, to a scalar multiple.  Since these eigenvectors do not share the same eigenvalue, they should be the same.  And it seems that they are, just multiplied by 209.

Comment: Minor: `-1.097+0.995j != -1.0970 + 0.9550i`, which doesn't help matters, but isn't the source of the issue (which seems indeed to be that Octave doesn't do what you might think it does with the second argument.)

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what's going on. Scipy is probably providing the correct eigenvalues. Octave [accepts a second matrix in its eig() function](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/eig.html) but doesn't specify what it does. [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#bti99bb-1) does say it's for a generalized eigenvalue problem, but in Octave adding the second matrix appears to have no affect on the eigenvalues. This looks like a bug in Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I have tried the same calculation with the [eig()](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg/#Base.eig) routine in Julia. (Here, for clarity, I have used symbols `A` and `B` for the generalized eigenvalue problem.)

```
A = [ 1.8000 + 0.0000im  -1.0970 + 0.9550im ;
     -1.0970 - 0.9550im   1.8000 + 0.0000im ]

B = [  209.0    0.0 ;
         0.0   209.0 ]

D, V = eig( A, B )

err = A * V - B * V * diagm(D)
@show vecnorm( err )
```

The result seems essentially the same as Scipy.

```
D = [0.0016533341538531843,0.015571546228921934]

V[:,1] = Complex{Float64}[0.03689085719366286 - 0.03211555936184871im,
                          0.048911598804451846 + 0.0im]
V[:,2] = Complex{Float64}[-0.03689085719366286 + 0.03211555936184871im,
                           0.048911598804451846 + 0.0im]

vecnorm(err) = 3.768784066493578e-17
```

On the other hand, if I try Octave with a `B` matrix having off-diagonal elements,

```
A = [ 1.8000 + 0.0000i  -1.0970 + 0.9550i ;
     -1.0970 - 0.9550i   1.8000 + 0.0000i ]

B = [ 1.0 5.0 ;
      5.0 3.0 ]

[ V, D ] = eig( A, B );

err = A * V - B * V * D ;
printf( "error = %20.10g\n", norm( err ) )
```

it gives the correct result:

```
V =
   0.73147 - 0.19955i  -0.96401 - 0.03599i
   0.74058 + 0.25942i   0.72711 - 0.17996i

D =
   Diagonal Matrix
   0.057841 - 0.000000i                      0
   0                     -0.883750 + 0.000000i

error =      1.814738616e-15
```

If I set `B` to diag( 209.0, 209.0 ) (as in the original post), Octave gives

```
V =
    0.53332 - 0.46429i  -0.53332 + 0.46429i
    0.70711 + 0.00000i   0.70711 + 0.00000i

D =
    Diagonal Matrix
    0.34555         0
    0               3.25445

error =          676.9262577
```

In fact, the above `V` and `D` are found to be the solution of a standard eigenvalue problem `A V = V D`. So it seems that when `B` is a diagonal matrix, Octave simply neglects it by assuming the unit matrix...

I used Octave3.4.3 (on Linux x86_64) and the result may be different for more recent versions.

Comment: Still the same in Octave 3.8.2